# Calculate top-3 scores, with specific exclusions in Excel

Tags: excel

I need to find the average of the top 3 values within a range, so have been using the following:

```
=IFERROR(SUM(LARGE(A2:F2,{1,2,3}))/3,Z2)
```

on a similar dataset to:

```
A  B  C  D  E  F  G
2  10 3  9  4  3  3
```

However, I now need to exclude either certain columns throughout that range (i.e. B, D, E etc), or to exclude some specific values from that range (whichever way is more efficient).

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Have you looked at averageifs(). Without example data to test...

Comment: please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: edited - apologies

Comment: "whichever way is more efficient" that depends on the logic on which you choose to exclude certain values. If you exclude BDE in your example, you only have 3 values left, so a simple average of ACF would suffice.

Comment: Fair point - I do need the top-3 values, as it's possible I'd have more columns - didn't make that clear enough

Comment: Is the criteria set, or changing, If changing how do you intend to tell the formula to exclude?  If set what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something you may be able to work with:

[image]

**In A3:**

```
{=AVERAGE(LARGE(A1:H1,ROW(1:3)))}
```

**In A4: (excluding B, D and E)**

```
{=AVERAGE(LARGE((A1;C1;F1:H1),ROW(1:3)))}
```

Notice it's an array formula and needs to be confirmed through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>